# To print number pyramid pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the number pattern for users given numbers. For eg: if the user enters 3 the program should generate 3 rows and looks like this:

```
     1
   2 3 2
 4 5 6 5 4
```

If user enters 4 and output must be:

```
      1
    2 3 2
  4 5 6 5 4
7 8 9 10 9 8 7
```

My code as below:

```
a=3
num = 1
num1=2
for x in range(0,a+1):
    for y in range(0,a-x):
        print(end="* ")
    for y in range(x,0,-1):
        print(num,end=" ")
        num=num+1
    for y in range(2,x+1):
        print(num1,end=" ")
        num1=num1+1
    print()
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/pyramid-patterns

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
rows = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))

k = 0
count=0
count1=0

for i in range(1, rows+1):
    for space in range(1, (rows-i)+1):
        print("  ", end="")
        count+=1
    
    while k!=((2*i)-1):
        if count<=rows-1:
            print(i+k, end=" ")
            count+=1
        else:
            count1+=1
            print(i+k-(2*count1), end=" ")
        k += 1
    
    count1 = count = k = 0
    print()
```

Comment: but after 3rd row output as 45643 but I want 45654